# EJB Website gives 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb

I have developed a simple jsp login page using netbeans with ejb. The problem starts when I run the ejb-war. It shows a normal login page and when i click submit, it shows me the 500 internal server error. Please help.

[image: Screenshot of error]

This is the error in full

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class   stateless.Mainpage
root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error  creating managed object for class: class stateless.Mainpage
root cause

com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=stateless.Mainpage/myuserFacade,Remote 3.x interface =stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote,refType=Session into class stateless.Mainpage: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/stateless.Mainpage/myuserFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
 root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/stateless.Mainpage/myuserFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=stateless.Mainpage/myuserFacade,Remote 3.x interface =stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote' in  SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote not found]]]
root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref  name=stateless.Mainpage/myuserFacade,Remote 3.x interface =stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote not found]]
root cause

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,  java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote not found]
root cause

 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:    stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote#stateless.MyuserFacadeRemote not found
```

I use a servlet to connect the java code to the jsp page like this

```
@EJB
private MyuserFacadeRemote myuserFacade;

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   // request.
   // String username = request.getParameter("username");
    System.out.println("TESTTEST");
   // System.out.println(username);
    //String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String res = myuserFacade.helloWorld();
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

MyuserFacade code

```
@Stateless
public class MyuserFacade implements MyuserFacadeRemote {
//EJBServer-ejbPU
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EJBServer-ejbPU")
private EntityManager em;



protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public MyuserFacade() {
    //super(Myuser.class);
}

public String helloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}

@Override
public List<Myuser> getAllUsers() {
   List<Myuser> userList = new ArrayList<Myuser>();
   userList = em.createNamedQuery("Myuser.findAll").getResultList();
   return userList;
}

@Override
public Myuser getUser(int userID) {
    Myuser aUser = new Myuser();
    aUser = (Myuser)em.createNamedQuery("Myuser.findByUserid").setParameter("userid", userID).getSingleResult();
    return aUser;
}



@Override
public String deleteUser(int userID) {
    Myuser aUser = getUser(userID);
    em.remove(aUser);
    return String.valueOf(userID);
}

@Override
public String createUser(int userid, String name, String password, String email, int tel, String address, String secqns, String secans) {
    Myuser aUser = new Myuser();
    aUser.setUserid(userid);
    aUser.setName(name);
    aUser.setPassword(password);
    aUser.setEmail(email);
    aUser.setTel(tel);
    aUser.setAddress(address);
    aUser.setSecqn(secqns);
    aUser.setSecans(secans);
    em.persist(aUser);
    return String.valueOf(userid);
}

@Override
public String updateUser(int userid, String name) {
    Myuser aUser = new Myuser();
    aUser = (Myuser)em.createNamedQuery("Myuser.findByUserid").setParameter("userid", userid).getSingleResult();
    aUser.setName(name);
    em.persist(aUser);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void updatePW(int userid, String newPW) {
    Myuser aUser = new Myuser();
    aUser = (Myuser)em.createNamedQuery("Myuser.findByUserid").setParameter("userid", userid).getSingleResult();
    aUser.setPassword(newPW);
    em.persist(aUser);

}

@Override
public Boolean verifyUser(String userName, String passWord) {
    Myuser aUser = new Myuser();
    aUser = (Myuser)em.createNamedQuery("Myuser.findByName").setParameter("name", userName).getSingleResult();
    String uName = aUser.getName();
    String uPass = aUser.getPassword();
    if(userName.equals(uName)&&passWord.equals(uPass)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do show the code for `MyuserFacadeRemote `.

Comment: @zulq I've added the code

Comment: Is your inerface a remote interface? Also `helloWorld()` should be `getHelloWorld()`.

Comment: There's a tutorial over here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/CreatingEJB3UsingNetbeansAndGlassfish